# Percentage "change factor"

Tags: percentages

In my math work book there’s a section on, when translated into english, “percentage change factor”. I am looking for the actual name for it in English in order to search more info/help regarding this.

I am not talking about: 
change/Original price for example 1320-320/1320.

I want to know what this is called:

Change factor = New value/old value: 
1200/1900 = 0.631

The 0.631 is the “change factor”.

Or

A camera cost $3750. The price was increased by 12%. What was the new price?

100% + 12% = 112%

The “change factor” is 1.12

Does anyone know what the actual name for the “change factor” in English?

Comment: Could it be percentage change, percent(age) difference, or relative percentage difference? Which are different names of the same thing, due to Wikipedia.

Comment: I would call it the *price changing factor*. Usually the $\text{ price change in percent}=\frac{P_t-P_0}{P_0}\cdot 100\text{%}$ is more relevant.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, I see what I can find.